# How do I set a field value in a VB.NET module using Reflection?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I set a field value in a VB.NET module using Reflection?

Comment: You may want to get a bit more specific and include some code or you're staring down-votes right in kisser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user287107 was close but this is what works:

```
    Dim ass As Assembly = Assembly.Load("AssemblyNameWhereModuleResides")
    Dim moduleType as Type = ass.GetType("MyNameSpaceIfApplicable.MyModuleName")
    moduleType.GetField("field").SetValue(Nothing, newValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

i think it should be very similar to the C# code

```
objectwithfield.GetType().GetField("field").SetValue(objectwithfield, newValue)
```