# Accessing variables thru reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, reflection, reference

I have a Windows Forms solution written in VB.NET. Using reflection from the Module MOD1 I want get/set public variable of Module MOD2. A strong constraint is to use just strings, as a command line interpreter would do. Here following there is the code I used to recreate the failing environment.

While accessing simple variable (useDialog) this code behaves as expected, but some problems rise while accessing complex variable (fWin or MainForm). I've made some mistake, but I don't realize which one!

Please note: fWin is a Windows Forms class.

```
Public Class fWin
    Public BoolValue As Boolean = True
    Public FileRoot As String = ""

    Private Sub fWin_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        mod1.MainForm = Me
        FileRoot = "My file root"
        mod2.Change()
    End Sub
End Class

Module mod1
    Public useDialog As Boolean
    Public PathRoot As String = "My path root"
    Public MainForm As fWin
End Module

Imports System.Reflection
Module mod2
    Dim currAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Public Function MemberSearch(memPathName As String, ByRef oParents() As Object) As Boolean
        Dim mcName() As String = memPathName.Split(".")
        Dim imc_scan As Integer
        Dim m_scan, currModule As [Module]
        Dim t_scan, currType As Type
        Dim f_scan, currField As FieldInfo
        Dim LoP As List(Of Object)

        currModule = Nothing
        currType = Nothing
        currField = Nothing
        LoP = New list(Of Object)
        Array.Resize(oParents, 0)

        imc_scan = 0
        For Each m_scan In currAssembly.GetModules()
            If (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(m_scan.Name) = mcName(imc_scan)) Then
                LoP.Add(m_scan)
                currModule = m_scan
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If (currModule Is Nothing) Then
            oParents = LoP.ToArray()
            Return False
        End If
        If (imc_scan >= (mcName.Length - 1)) Then
            oParents = LoP.ToArray()
            Return True
        Else
            imc_scan += 1
            For Each t_scan In currModule.GetTypes()
                If (t_scan.Name = mcName(imc_scan)) Then
                    LoP.Add(t_scan)
                    currType = t_scan
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If (currType Is Nothing) Then
                oParents = LoP.ToArray()
                Return False
            Else
                If (imc_scan >= (mcName.Length - 1)) Then
                    oParents = LoP.ToArray()
                    Return True
                End If

                Dim bf As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.IgnoreCase

                While (currType IsNot Nothing) AndAlso currType.IsValueType = False And (imc_scan < (mcName.Length - 1))
                    imc_scan += 1
                    currField = Nothing
                    For Each f_scan In currType.GetFields(bf)
                        If (String.Compare(f_scan.Name, mcName(imc_scan), True) = 0) Then
                            LoP.Add(f_scan)
                            currField = f_scan
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If currField Is Nothing Then
                        oParents = LoP.ToArray()
                        Return False
                    Else
                        dim Container as object = nothing
                        try
                            Container = LoP.Last
                            if (imc_scan >= (mcName.Length - 1)) then
                                Container = LoP(LoP.Count - 2)
                            end if
                            currType = Container
                        catch ex As Exception
                            currType = Nothing
                        end try
                        if ( currType is nothing ) then
                            try
                                Container = Container.GetValue( nothing )
                                LoP.Add( Container.GetType().GetField( mcName( imc_scan+1 ) ) )
                            catch ex1 as Exception
                                MessageBox.Show( ex1.Message )
                            end try
                        end if
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        End If

        oParents = LoP.ToArray()
        Return (imc_scan <= (mcName.Length - 1))
    End Function

    Public Sub Change()
        Dim ao() As Object

        Debug.WriteLine("")
        Debug.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------")
        Debug.WriteLine("")
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(0).Name)
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(1).Name)
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1.useDialog", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(2).Name & " = " & ao(2).GetValue(ao(1)))
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1.PathRoot", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(2).Name & " = " & ao(2).GetValue(ao(1)))
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.fWin.BoolValue", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(2).Name & " = " & ao(2).GetValue(ao(1)))
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.fWin.FileRoot", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(2).Name & " = " & ao(2).GetValue(ao(1)))
        If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1.MainForm.FileRoot", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(3).Name & " = " & ao(3).GetValue(ao(2)))
    End Sub
End Module
```

The error "Additional information: Field 'BoolValue' defined on type 'sov_reflXn.fWin' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'System.RuntimeType'." occurs on the line starting with the following text: if MemberSearch( "sov_reflXn.fWin.BoolValue", ... The main problem is how to 'solve' fWin.
I beg Your pardon for the delay of my previous post, and I thank You all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FieldInfo.GetValue` requires an object instance in order to get the value of the field, but you are passing it a `System.Type`: you're passing it the type info for `sov_reflXn.fWin` rather than an instance of it.

Since you have the type, you could get a constructor through reflection, but that's probably not what you really want to do.  You'll need to figure out a good way to get the instance you want to manipulate to your code.

If you have an instance available from a module, you can use the answer here: [How do I set a field value in a VB.NET module using Reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692944/how-do-i-set-a-field-value-in-a-vb-net-module-using-reflection)
Substitute `GetValue` for `SetValue`, and pass `Nothing` as the instance, e.g.

```
Call MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1.MainForm.FileRoot", ao)
Debug.WriteLine(ao(1).GetField("PathRoot").GetValue(Nothing))
```

Comment: You're right. So I've used the variable **public MainForm as fWin**, declared in mod1 and set during the form load event. But the problem still exist. How to resolve fWin/MainForm names into their instances?? There's a set of conditions to check to figure out what I have to do: use GetValue or get the underlying instance?

Comment: @Billy see edited answer.  Judicious searching should find more info on getting instances of variables using reflection.

Comment: The **Debug.WriteLine(ao(1).GetField("PathRoot")..** line You have written here above was already functioning. Try the last **Debug.WriteLine** in my code: You will get the error ...

Comment: @Billy The `Debug.WriteLine` line in my answer is new, it's not in your code.  It shows how to get `PathRoot` from `mod1`.  You can follow the same approach to get an instance of `MainForm` from `mod1`.  I've edited the answer further to make it a little more clear.

Comment: Thank You, Craig! I've made a step forward! But I would do a step more to get the routine functioning. The statement **If MemberSearch("sov_reflXn.mod1.MainForm.FileRoot", ao) Then Debug.WriteLine(ao(3).Name & " = " & ao(3).GetValue(ao(2)))** will continue to fail with the same error. After I have read your last comment, I've executed the command **Container.GetType().GetField("FileRoot").GetValue(Container)** in the Immediate Window when the second try-body was just ended and the result was great! Please let me know where I do the mistake ... Many thanks in advance.